# Help Needed in Modelling

Tags: modeling

I am trying tmodel a scenario using UML and later code in c#. I am not sure how to do this with UMl diagram. Any help is appreciated.

A department consist of groups. Within groups there can be teams and with in teams there are team members. At each level there is a policy which is inherited by the the next levels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to build a UML class diagram (there are other diagrams too), take a look at [this general explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram). The "department consists of groups" relations (and the other ones too) be modeled using [Aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregation_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Aggregation).